# How to replace push buttons on an intercom?

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit, amperage, button, watts

This is the intercom panel in my apartment, it's 30+ years old and I want to give it a face lift. The push-buttons are momentary, and I want to replace them using modern ones like these, but I'm not sure what considerations must be made for voltage/amps. If it helps, the wiring diagram (last photo) shows how the intercom connects to the master unit, I emphasized where the buttons reside and how they short the circuit to active talk/listen/door functions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not worked on this particular system before, but I have worked on some older intercom systems. The current going through these buttons won't be much. To be sure, get ones that are fine to handle a few hundred mA and you will be fine.

It looks like it is a 16V system, but again, to be safe, get a  24V rated button.

The next bit is where you will have to be careful. You can see where the buttons are connected, but your new buttons are likely to be physically longer than the current ones. You will need to desolder the current buttons, and remove them. If you can, move the PCB out of the way.

Next, you will have to make a new hole for the new buttons to fit in. Chances are your new buttons will be longer than the current ones. Make sure you make a hole that the button can sit in, and be securely fixed with the nut on the back. Then simply solder wires from the button to the PCB. Use your photographs to make sure each one is wired to the correct place.

*This could well be more trouble than it is worth and there is a chance you could damage the system, and break it. Only attempt this if you are 100% confident you can do it, or if you have the money to pay for a callout fee for it to be repaired if something goes wrong.*

Going by the photos, you can make out the manufacturer; LeeDan. The model number is also handily written; IR081-C.

Googling this will take you to [THIS PAGE](http://www.leedan.com/IR-081C.htm) where the company does actually offer their own 'facelift' upgrades to this panel. If you are intent on doing a DIY job, then maybe [THIS DATASHEET](http://www.leedan.com/IN-826.pdf) may be of use.

Comment: As a friend of mine would say: "It was already broken when I broke it"

Comment: @WesleyLee Yeah, that's the general response. May be difficult to use that excuse here if you reshape the button holes and have shiny new ones though! Lol.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you, I won't be using the same plastic panel, I'm replacing it with jet black acrylic so I can drill new holes for the speaker and buttons to exact sizes. When it's done it will look very "cool", whether it works or not is secondary :-)

Comment: Forgot to ask, how many leads should the push buttons have? Some have 2 others have 5, I guess I'll know when I remove the originals from the circuit board.

Comment: @raffian Looking at the wiring diagram and the circuit board shown in the picture, thy each have 2 leads. You can see the screw terminals have 1, 2, 3 and X marked on them, same as on the wiring diagram. You can match the buttons to the correct screw terminal using the diagram. I must assume that the other side of it will also have wires which go to the main controller, so be sure to do it one at a time so you don't forget where each one goes

Comment: @raffian please also see the additional information I have added to my answer

Comment: @MCG Yup, I found the data sheet last night, that's where I got the wiring schematic. With your additional information I think this will work out really nice, thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Enjoy the project!